# Google Charts API DataTable Cell Color

Tags: javascript, json, perl, google-visualization

I'm trying to use the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) to display a [`DataTable`](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable) which has some of its cells coloured depending on their value. The table generates fine, but none of my style properties are applied to the cells. According to the documentation I should be able to set a cell value using the [`p`](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#dataparam) value:

> p [Optional] An object that is a map of custom values applied to the cell. These values can be of any JavaScript type. If your visualisation supports any cell-level properties, it will describe them; otherwise, this property will be ignored. Example: p:{style: 'border: 1px solid green;'}.

I'm passing a Perl generated JSON object to the `DataTable` constructor. The JSON object looks like this:

```
{"cols":[{"pattern":"","type":"string","label":"alias","id":""},
        {"pattern":"","type":"string","label":"state","id":""},
        {"pattern":"","type":"string","label":"server_name","id":""},
        {"pattern":"","type":"number","label":"connections","id":""},
        {"pattern":"","type":"number","label":"sessions","id":""},
        {"pattern":"","type":"number","label":"queues","id":""},
        {"pattern":"","type":"number","label":"topics","id":""},
        {"pattern":"","type":"number","label":"durables","id":""},
        {"pattern":"","type":"number","label":"pending_message","id":""}
    ],
"rows":[
        {"c":[{"v":"live1"},
        {"p":{"style":"border: 1px solid green;"},"v":"Active"},
        {"v":"serice1"},{"v":"580"},{"v":"1177"},{"v":"632"},{"v":"200"},{"v":"68"},{"v":"69"}
    ]},
    {"c":[
        {"v":"live2"},
        {"p":{"style":"border: 1px solid green;"},"v":"Active"},
        {"v":"service2"},{"v":"68"},{"v":"1481"},{"v":"164"},{"v":"48"},{"v":"4"},{"v":"2592"}
    ]},
    {"c":[
        {"v":"uat1"},
        {"p":{"style":"border: 1px solid green;"},
        "v":"Active"},{"v":"service3"},{"v":"299"},{"v":"1072"},{"v":"305"},{"v":"111"},{"v":"39"},{"v":"17"}]},
    {"c":[
        {"v":"uat2"},
        {"p":{"style":"border: 1px solid green;"},
        "v":"Active"},{"v":"service4"},{"v":"115"},{"v":"1755"},{"v":"302"},{"v":"79"},{"v":"9"},{"v":"1"}]
    }],
"p":null}
```

Can any one see what I'm doing wrong, or have an example JSON object structure of a `DataTable` with style applied to cells or rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok looks like I missed something:

in the dataTable options you have to set 'allowHtml: true'
Then all formatting properties will be accepted, hope this saves someone a bit of digging around, although it is fairly obvious :-s